# How can I set the value of certain elements in a 2D array having their positions in a list with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Given an 2D array (initialised with `0`s), I want to

- to change the value of certain array elements from 0 to 1, where
- the 1-based positions of elements to be changed are given in a list `numbers` like `[2,5,10,50]`.

For example, given `array = np.zeros([5,10])` and `numbers = [2,5,10,50]` I expect the output of `print(array)` to be:

```
[[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros([5,10],dtype=int).reshape(-1,1)

numbers = [2,5,10]

def draw_ships(array, numbers):
    numbers = np.sort(numbers)
    for i in numbers:
        array[i] = 1

draw_ships(array, numbers)
print(array)
```

doesn't give me the expected output, but

```
[[0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [0]
# more output
 [0]
 [0]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please tell what output is expected. What are exemplary inputs?

Comment: do you want to modify just the first row?

Comment: please put it to question, not comment. PLease tell what is the desired **input** in case of 2D array

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. After reviewing your question here, I recommend to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and ***read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.zeros((5, 10), dtype=int)
numbers = [2, 5, 10, 50]

array.flat[np.array(numbers) - 1] = 1

print(array)
```

implements what you'd like to have and prints out

```
[[0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```